# Pig ERROR 1075: Received a bytearray from the UDF. Cannot determine how to convert the bytearray to string

Tags: apache-pig, bigdata

I am new to pig. I have some data in dataset like the below.

### data:

```
(U,Y,,,,,,)
(U,U,U,U,W,,,)
(U,U,U,U,U,Y,,)
```

I need to convert it to individual group rows excluding blank fields.

Output should be like the below

```
(U,10)
(Y,2)
(W,1)
```

I have tried the below code.

```
B = foreach data generate FLATTEN(TOBAG(*)) as leads;
```

After the above statement all columns gets converted to rows with one field and I want to filter the blank rows. So I use the below.

```
C= FILTER B BY leads != '';
```

But its giving the below error

> Pig ERROR 1075: Received a bytearray from the UDF. Cannot determine
>   how to convert the bytearray to string

I even tried casting to chararray as below.

```
C= FILTER B BY (chararray)leads != '';
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 1):

No need to cast.This will work.After that group by $0 and COUNT($0) get the output.

```
C = FILTER B BY leads is not null;
```

[image]

```
D = GROUP C BY $0;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE group,COUNT(C);
DUMP E;
```

[image]